# Double clicking an item in datagridview gives an "Index out of range error"

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

I'm getting the following error

Comment: What if there are no rows selected?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your index is out of range and you need to pout in the required checks for those.  You need to check for selected rows before setting the text. Wrap the logic inside an 'if condition' and check there before you proceed.

Comment: you're not supposed to **ever** use `[N]` syntax unless you 100% sure, there is something in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only 2 rows then change 1 => 0 and 2 => 1
remember you are selecting from an Array and arrays start at 0

if they 1 is cell 2 and 2 is cell 3 and you are correct then i am not sure what your problem can be without actually seeing your datagrid